# Brownian motion or not?

Tags: brownian-motion

Suppose that $(X_t , t\in [0;1])$ are independent normal r.v with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2 _{t}$. Is this process brownian motion?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You first need $\sigma_t=t$, since the Brownian motion should have variance $t$ at time $t$.

A condition for $X$ to be a Brownian motion is that for any $s<t$,
$$X_t-X_s\sim N(0,t-s)\qquad (1).$$

From the independence of $X_t$ and $X_s$, you get
$$X_t-X_s\sim N(0,t+s),$$
which is a contradiction to the condition $(1)$.

Comment: Why it variance is t+s?

Comment: This comes from the independence of the normal random variables $X_t$ and $X_s$. See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **never**, because, if $(W_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is a Brownian motion, then $W_{1/2}$ and $W_1$ are not independent while you assumed that $X_{1/2}$ and $X_1$ are independent.

Comment: It is the *increments* that are independent.

Comment: @GEdgar The increments of a Brownian motion: yes. The increments of the process $(X_t)$ in this question: no. Which is the point of this answer. Is this also the point of your (rather cryptic) comment?

Comment: Yes, the (cryptic) comment was to help Mex understand better.